# Want to install a build in one particular device when multiple devices are connected to ADB

Tags: adb

I have connected 2 devices to my laptop. In adb devices it is showing 2 devices (obviously). Now I want to install a build in one particular device. How to select one of them. Is there any command for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an extra option to the adb command. First, use `adb devices` to get the device serial numbers. Let's call those *serialA* and *serialB*. Then you can use the `-s SERIALNUMBER` option to adb to tell it which device to talk to:

`adb -s serialA shell ls`

will give you a directory listing of the root of *serialA*'s filesystem.

If you want to work with a device for an extended period, you can set the environment variable ANDROID_SERIAL to the device's serial number. Using the `-s` option overrides ANDROID_SERIAL.

However, if you're flashing a device, I'd recommend unplugging the one you don't want to flash. That's a good deal safer than trusting yourself not to make any typing errors.